# Zend Framework 2 Doctrine 2 BJ Younglbood Profiler Reports Undefined index db

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm setting up a new Zend Framework 2 Doctrine 2 app and have included BJ Youngblood's profiler.  However, after including it, I now receive the error `Undefined index: db` in `ProfilingAdapterFactory.php`.  My doctrine.local.php in /config/autoload contains all my database parameters.  The contents of ProfilingAdapterFactory that have not been edited are as follows:

```
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
{
    $config = $serviceLocator->get('Configuration');
    $dbParams = $config['db'];
    $adapter = new ProfilingAdapter($dbParams);

    $adapter->setProfiler(new Profiler);
    if (isset($dbParams['options']) && is_array($dbParams['options'])) {
        $options = $dbParams['options'];
    } else {
        $options = array();
    }
    $adapter->injectProfilingStatementPrototype($options);
    return $adapter;
}
```

How do I adjust the ProfiliingAdapterFactory.php to see the doctrine database parameters?

Comment: Can you show you're config files please ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youngblood's profiler is for Zend\Db profiling. 
If you need a profiler for Doctrine ORM, it's already included in Doctrine ORM module for ZF2, so all you need to do, is install this module via composer as well as zend-developer-tools

```
"doctrine/doctrine-orm-module" : "0.*",
"zendframework/zend-developer-tools" : "dev-master",
```